# Datagridview with checkbox

Tags: .net, gridview, datagridview

I Have Tried this, but not getting selected value to another grid view

```
string data = "";
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView5.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCtr") CheckBox);
            if (chkRow.Checked)
            {
                string Brand_Name = row.Cells[1].Text;
                string Market_Name = row.Cells[2].Text;
                string USC = row.Cells[3].Text;
                string Manufacture = row.Cells[4].Text;
                data = data + Brand_Name + " ,  ";
                //;+ Market_Name + " , " + USC + ","+Manufacture+"";

                gvrProducts.Visible = true;


                gvrProducts.DataSource = data;
                // ListBox1.DataBind();
                gvrProducts.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

GridView requires [data source control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227679(v=vs.100).aspx) such as a LinqDataSource, ObjectDataSource, or SqlDataSource control. You are binding your gridview with a string variable(don't know how it bind data).There are many way to bind the gridview but I am explain the one of way by creating dynamic DataTable:

Create a Empty DataTable for second gridview:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 DataRow dr = null;
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Brand_Name", typeof(string)));
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Market_Name", typeof(string)));
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("USC", typeof(string)));
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Manufacture", typeof(string)));
```

After that add rows to this datatable inside your foreach loop:

```
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView5.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkCtr") CheckBox);
                if (chkRow.Checked)
                {
                 dr = dt.NewRow();
                 dr["Brand_Name"] = row.Cells[1].Text;
                 dr["Market_Name"] = row.Cells[2].Text;
                 dr["USC"] = row.Cells[3].Text;
                 dr["Manufacture"] = row.Cells[4].Text;
                 dt.Rows.Add(dr);                 

                }
            }
        }
```

Then bind your gridview with Datatable

```
if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
{
 gvrProducts.Visible = true;
 gvrProducts.DataSource = dt;
 gvrProducts.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Wow, Thats Ultimate Solutions !!.. Thank You. I Will Come With More Doubts ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this

```
Private Sub Gridview_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Gridview.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    Gridview.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
End Sub
```

Then

```
Private Sub Gridview_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Gridview.CellValueChanged
    Try
        Gridview.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
        'add commit when chckbox is checked. Then your procedure/staff here.
        'Or call your for loop here
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```